# Log4j with two outputs with log4j.properties?

Tags: java, file, logging, configuration, log4j

I want to use the Log4j API but I encountered a little problem with the configuration.

This is my LogWriter Class:

```
public class LogWriter {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogWriter.class);

    public LogWriter(String logFilePath) {
        File outFile = new File(logFilePath);
        try {
            PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
            System.setOut(outStream));    
            System.setErr(outStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not Found");
        }
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    public void write(String infoString) {
        logger.info(infoString);
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, but I can't write into the Logger-File and the Console at the same time (probably because of `System.setOut`)

I added a log4j.properties File that looks like this:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console

# Direct log messages to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p- %m%n
```

Now my question is, how can I make my LogWriter and the log4j.properties File work together, so that the Output comes into the Logger-File and the Console?
What do I have to change in my LogWriter?

Comment: Just one question, before I could help you; why you are creating a Logwriter, when you can customize whole log writing by using log4j api and its configuration?

Comment: Why are you using a custom file logger when Log4J provides one? You would only have to configure one more appender in the log4j.properties file.

Comment: Well, somehow a lot of examples had a custom Logging Class... Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to reinventing the same wheel? add ConsoleAppender and FileAppender in your log4j, you could get the log in both place. Can you be more specific what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before installing your `LogWriter`, you must keep copies of the original references stored in `System.out` and `System.err` somewhere. Use them to write a new appender. Configure log4j to use this appender in `log4j.appender.console`.

Background: The default log4j `ConsoleAppender` just writes to `System.out`. If you change it, log4j will use whatever you supply. There is no way to configure `ConsoleAppender` to write somewhere else. In your `LogWriter`, it's not possible to distinguish between output coming from log4j and `System.out.println()`.

So the only solution is to write another appender which writes to the original `System.out`.

That said, it might be smarter to use the original `ConsoleAppender` and use a `FileAppender` instead of your own `LogWriter`. Just make sure you never use `System.out` directly anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the output block and that solved my problem